# Calculate the 3 sigma value using python

Tags: python, statistics, analysis

I have one data frame in python. How can I **calculate the 3sigma value** for each column of my data frame using python? please help me with this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please try to add that in your question. And your research results about your problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is `df.std() * 3`